# Is it rigorous? Solve an optimization problem by letting a parameter approach to $0$ that should be exactly $0$.

Tags: calculus, limits, optimization, convex-optimization

Assume we have a simple mean-variance model given by
$\min_{x\in\mathcal{X}} \lambda x^{\top}\Sigma x - \mu^{\top}x$, where $ \mathcal{X} = \{x:1^{\top}x=1,x\geq 0 \} $ and $\Sigma$ is positive definite .
If one totally ignores risk, he may set $\lambda = 0$. Here is my problem. Instead of setting $\lambda = 0 $ directly (in this case, the resulting model $\min_{x\in\mathcal{X}} - \mu^{\top}x$ is easy to solve), can I take $\lambda = \epsilon $ where $ \epsilon >0$ is a small number and then obtain the results by letting $\epsilon $ approach to $0$? Is it a rigorous or reasonable way of solving a general optimization problem with a parameter equal to $0$?

Comment: Not really. Take $\Sigma=I$ for example. Then a solution exists for all $\lambda >0$ but not for $\lambda = 0$.

Comment: @copper.hat I updated the description. For $\lambda =0$, there should be a obvious solution that invests all the fund 1 into the asset with the highest expected return in $\mu$.

Comment: What do you mean by rigorous? As long as the objective function is continuous for all $\lambda$ that you want to consider in some set $\Lambda$, $\mathcal{X}$ is compact so a solution exists. The behavior of the solution and optimized objective function is then given by Berge's Theorem of the Maximum. What else would you like to know about the solution correspondence besides existence and upper hemi-continuity?

Comment: Many people would call this a homotopy. It's often used in computational work, when you have a problem that is easy to solve ($\lambda = 0$) but you need a good guess for some other case ($\lambda \gg 0$). People take very small steps, getting a good guess for the next step until they reach the desired result. This can be usually described by a set of differential algebraic equations and the global convergence properties studied that way.

Comment: @Renard The motivation of this question is that we can first easily obtain a solution with $\lambda >0 $ (we can optimize over a quadratic function). But if we want to let $\lambda = 0$, the original problem may be different (not quadratic any more in this case). The question is that whether we can obtain the new solution with $\lambda = 0$ by taking a limit based on the old solution with $\lambda > 0$?

Comment: The problem $\min_{x \in \mathcal{X}} - \mu'x$ subject to $x \ge 0$ and $1'x =1$ is just a linear programming problem. It might have a correspondence/set-valued solution, in which case a sequence of optimizers $x^*(\lambda)$, $\lambda>0$, will converge to an element of $x^*(0)$, but not every element of $x^*(0)$ can be reached by such a sequence. That is what it means for a correspondence to be upper hemi-continuous.

Comment: This is super helpful for parameterized optimization problems : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_theorem

Comment: In the particular case of this problem, it is not too difficult to show that the solutions of the regularised problems converge to **a** solution. In general (meaning a $\min$ function over a variable in a compact set) the best one can hope for is that any accumulation point of the regularised minimisers will also be a minimiser for the un regularised problem.